# How can I play a streaming URL in an android app?

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

I would like to play a streaming URL in an android app. I have checked out the MediaPlayer but it's not working. My possible extensions are m3u, pls, asx, and ram.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to add more details about what is not working about MediaPlayer.  Inevitably, if you want to stream video or audio, media player will be involved unless you want to write your own media player or use a third party alternative.  Show us what code you used and what errors it produced and we can try to help.

Comment: Following is the code I am trying with. It doesn't produce any errors but when I debug the code, it throws an IOException on the mp.prepare() call. I have checked the URL and it is functional.

`MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource("http://public.wavepanel.net/RFBZ5ZIGBC5LY8OW/listen/m3u");
mp.prepare();
mp.start();`

Answer (score 0):

Yxplayer dose i am streaming from home

Answer (score 0):

These are few best players to play url links

1. MX PLAYER - play: http,rtmp,rtsp,mms,mmsh
2. MOBO PLAYER - play: only rtsp

Just type moboplayer.apk OR mxplayer.apk then download>install
To get more url just go to livetvstreaming.com